# Firefox screen share MediaStreamTrack to Twilio

Tags: javascript, firefox, twilio, screensharing

I use Firefox v55.0.2

In documentation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia), after NavigatorUserMedia.getUserMedia() normally in successCallback i have a MediaStream but in my case i have LocalMediaStream.

I need to have MediaStreamTrack to give it at twilio.

This is my code :

```
$scope.testShareFirefox = function () {
  var p = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: {
      mediaSource: 'screen',
      width: 640,
      height: 480
    },
  })
  .then(function(stream) {
    const screenLocalTrack = new twilio.Video.LocalVideoTrack(stream);
    $scope.videoConf.room.localParticipant.addTrack(screenLocalTrack);

    var video = document.createElement('video');
    $('#test-share-screen').append(video);

    video.srcObject = stream;
    video.play();
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
};
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

LocalMediaStream is Inheritance of MediaStream so we can use ".getTracks()"

This is the work solution :

```
$scope.testShareFirefox = function () {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: {
      mediaSource: 'screen',
      width: 640,
      height: 480
    },
  })
  .then(function(stream) {
    stream.getTracks().forEach(function(track) {
      $scope.videoConf.room.localParticipant.addTrack(track);
    });

    var video = document.createElement('video');
    $('#test-share-screen').append(video);

    video.srcObject = stream;
    video.play();
    var trackElements = document.querySelectorAll("track");
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
};
```